# SQL Count is showing distinct names but not correct number of matches

Tags: sql, count

I have a table with the following values:

name_table

```
ID  Name  
1   Bob  
2   James  
3   Bob  
4   Joe
```

I am trying to do a search where it will give me the list names and how many times the name was found. What I am looking for is a result like this:

```
Bob 2  James 1  Joe 1
```

The code:

```
(connection info)  
$query = "SELECT name, count(*) FROM name_table GROUP BY name;  
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die (Could not execute query"); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result)) 
echo ("$row['name']");
```

It is showing me the names (Bob James Joe) but not the count.

Answer (score 1):

The query looks right, it should return what you want. The problem is that you don't print the count.

Try to change your query to this:

```
SELECT name, count(*) 'count' FROM name_table GROUP BY name
```

And your echo line to:

```
echo ("$row['name'] $row['count']");
```

Comment: Sahin, I tried as you suggested and nothing shows, not even an error.

Comment: Can you try like that: echo ({"$row['name']} {$row['count']}")

Comment: Sahin, that is almost spot on, it shows Bob2James1Joe1 but has an extra number 2 in front of Bob

Comment: Sahin, i found my error it works. Thank you so much.